# Showing a module over $C[0,1] $ is not free

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Define $R:= \lbrace f \in C [0,1] \mid f(0)=f(1) \rbrace$, $V:= \lbrace f \in C [0,1] \mid f(0)=-f(1) \rbrace$.
> $V$ is an $R$-module. I have no idea how to show it is not free.

I have tried to construct some function that hope can show $V$ has no independent set, but I find it hard to show it is continuous such that belongs to $R$.
Is there any  other way to show $V$ is not free?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a fun example...

Comment: Moreover, one can show that $V\oplus V\simeq R\oplus R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f_1,f_2\in V$, then we have $(f_2^2)f_1-(f_1f_2)f_2=0$, so every two elements of $V$ are linearly dependent. Suppose that $V$ is free. Then $V$ is cyclic, that is, $V=Rf$. Since $f(0)f(1)\le0$ it follows that $f$ vanishes at a point $a\in[0,1]$. On the other side, $V$ contains functions that don't vanish at $a$.

Comment: Wow, so this example also involves some basic knowledge from analysis, that was fun! Thanks for your help